# GetModifiedMembers returns empty array

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

The code below always return an empty array from `GetModifiedMembers(object)`
but `dx.GetChangeSet().Updates.Contains( foo )` returns true.

```
DataContext dx = new DataContext( string.Empty );
MockLinqDataObject foo = new MockLinqDataObject();
dx.GetTable( foo.GetType() ).Attach( foo );

foo.PK = Guid.NewGuid();

// always returns empty array
ModifiedMemberInfo[] arr_Result = dx.GetTable( foo.GetType() ).GetModifiedMembers( foo );
bool isOk = ( arr_Result.Length == 1 );
return isOk;
```

Does anyone know what there is wrong?

Thanks in advance?

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't an answer but I haven't been able to replicate your issue.

Using the following code in a console application I get an array of length 1:

```
testdbDataContext db = new testdbDataContext();
Address a = new Address();
db.GetTable(a.GetType()).Attach(a);
a.Address1 = "simple change";

var result = db.GetTable(a.GetType()).GetModifiedMembers(a);
Console.WriteLine(result.Length);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Console output is `1`.

Try modifying another property on the foo object and see if your result differs.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the length after you SubmitChanges, then you would get length as 0 because the changes in data context gets cleared after changes get submitted.